# php for statement to fetch mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing the names and types of images in my database. Now I want to select the newest images from that database and display them to the user. I tried to use the following code but I am getting the same image name and type, but I want to get different images.

```
$new_image_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM newest");
$result = mysql_result($new_image_count, 0);

    $select_images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newest");

        $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_images);
        for($result; $result > 0; $result--){

        $name = $fetch['image_name'];
        $type = $fetch['image_type'];
        $name_dot_type = $name.".".$type;
        echo '<img src="main_images/'.$name_dot_type.'" width="300">';
        }
```

Any ideas about how to fix this problem ?

Comment: I would highly recommend switching from mysql to mysqli or pdo

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (Lack of research). Every tutorial, book and manual page about the mysql_* functions will tell you exactly how to loop over the resultset.

Comment: what do you mean by  - "I am getting the same image name and type,"?

Comment: @ Eswar Rajesh Pinapala the code is echoing the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the query to count rows (you don't need it)

and change the main part of the code to something like

```
$select_images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newest");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_images)) {
    // echo data from $fetch
}
```

PS: you'll recently get a comments about using PDO instead of `mysql_`

PPS: you get the same results because you fetch the row just once, and after that you output the same values in the loop

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*()` functions anymore, and should switch to mysqli or PDO

Secondly, just move the `$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_images);` inside the `for` loop:

```
for($result; $result > 0; $result--){
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_images);
    $name = $fetch['image_name'];
    $type = $fetch['image_type'];
    $name_dot_type = $name.".".$type;
    echo '<img src="main_images/'.$name_dot_type.'" width="300">';
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `$result` value ever

Comment: I wouldn't either, but its his code.  I am just making it work for him.

Comment: @Saad Alhly: your current solution is terrible - you don't need to count amount of rows and perform `for()` at all. PS: learning is when you read **all** the answers, not just follow the first one